# Golang 2 домена 1 ip

Tags: golang

У Apache есть vhost. Как это реализовать чисто на Go? Какой нибудь пример?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func indexGo1(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    rw.Write([]byte("hello go1.dev"))
}

func indexGo2(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    rw.Write([]byte("hello go2.dev"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("go1.dev/", indexGo1)
    http.HandleFunc("go2.dev/", indexGo2)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Домены `go1.dev` и `go2.dev` должны быть добавлены в `/etc/hosts`.